# Is there a way to show available commands in discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

If you use rythm or other bots you will get suggitions when you type "/". Is there a way to do the same with discord.py? I was writing a bot and want to add this feature

Comment: Not yet supported in discord.py

Comment: See https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/6149

Comment: thanks discord-py-slash-command seems to work